# my mongo aggregation is PROJECTION_DEFAULT not PROJECTION_COVERED even if there are not fetch stage

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wanted to understand under what cirumstance a quey which has only `IXSCAN` stage and no `FETCH` stage **not** be a `PROJECTION_COVERED`  query but a `PROJECTION_DEFAULT` query.
I have execution stats of similar kind of aggregation queries. One gives `PROJECTION_COVERED`  while other gives `PROJECTION_DEFAULT` . In both queries all required fields are part of index and that indes is also being picked. I am attaching execution stats of both queries. Both are aggregation pipelines with similar match and group operation only. all fields are covered in index.

`PROJECTION_COVERED` :

```
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "nReturned" : 524400,
                    "executionTimeMillis" : 2097,
                    "totalKeysExamined" : 524401,
                    "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
                        "nReturned" : 524400,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 231,
                        "works" : 524401,
                        "advanced" : 524400,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 587,
                        "restoreState" : 587,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "transformBy" : {
                            "cessValue" : 1,
                            "cgstValue" : 1,
                            "differentialTaxRate" : 1,
                            "igstValue" : 1,
                            "placeOfSupply" : 1,
                            "sgstValue" : 1,
                            "supplyTypeType" : 1,
                            "totalTaxRate" : 1,
                            "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 524400,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 181,
                            "works" : 524401,
                            "advanced" : 524400,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 587,
                            "restoreState" : 587,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sellerGstin" : 1.0,
                                "returnPeriod" : 1.0,
                                "documentType" : 1.0,
                                "placeOfSupply" : 1.0,
                                "supplyTypeType" : 1.0,
                                "totalTaxRate" : 1.0,
                                "differentialTaxRate" : 1.0,
                                "cgstValue" : 1.0,
                                "sgstValue" : 1.0,
                                "igstValue" : 1.0,
                                "cessValue" : 1.0,
                                "taxableValue" : 1.0
                            },
                            "indexName" : "line_item_index_for_b2cs",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sellerGstin" : [],
                                "returnPeriod" : [],
                                "documentType" : [],
                                "placeOfSupply" : [],
                                "supplyTypeType" : [],
                                "totalTaxRate" : [],
                                "differentialTaxRate" : [],
                                "cgstValue" : [],
                                "sgstValue" : [],
                                "igstValue" : [],
                                "cessValue" : [],
                                "taxableValue" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sellerGstin" : [ 
                                    "[\"92L4YI1LN7TQF2EA\", \"92L4YI1LN7TQF2EA\"]"
                                ],
                                "returnPeriod" : [ 
                                    "[\"122021\", \"122021\"]"
                                ],
                                "documentType" : [ 
                                    "[\"CREDIT\", \"CREDIT\"]", 
                                    "[\"DEBIT\", \"DEBIT\"]", 
                                    "[\"INVOICE\", \"INVOICE\"]"
                                ],
                                "placeOfSupply" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "supplyTypeType" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "totalTaxRate" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "differentialTaxRate" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "cgstValue" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "sgstValue" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "igstValue" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "cessValue" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "taxableValue" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 524401,
                            "seeks" : 1,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    }
                }
```

`PROJECTION_DEFAULT` :

````
                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                    "nReturned" : 126,
                    "executionTimeMillis" : 9,
                    "totalKeysExamined" : 134,
                    "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                    "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION_DEFAULT",
                        "nReturned" : 126,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 134,
                        "advanced" : 126,
                        "needTime" : 7,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 1,
                        "restoreState" : 1,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "transformBy" : {
                            "assessableAmount" : 1,
                            "cessAmount" : 1,
                            "cgstAmount" : 1,
                            "documentDetails.documentType" : 1,
                            "gstRate" : 1,
                            "hsnCode" : 1,
                            "igstAmount" : 1,
                            "quantity" : 1,
                            "sgstAmount" : 1,
                            "totalAmount" : 1,
                            "unit" : 1,
                            "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned" : 126,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                            "works" : 134,
                            "advanced" : 126,
                            "needTime" : 7,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 1,
                            "restoreState" : 1,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "gstinOrgId" : 1.0,
                                "invoiceMetadata.returnPeriod" : 1.0,
                                "isDeleted" : 1.0,
                                "documentGstStatus" : 1.0,
                                "status" : 1.0,
                                "invoiceMetadata.sectionName" : 1.0,
                                "documentDetails.documentType" : 1.0,
                                "hsnCode" : 1.0,
                                "unit" : 1.0,
                                "gstRate" : 1.0,
                                "totalAmount" : 1.0,
                                "assessableAmount" : 1.0,
                                "cgstAmount" : 1.0,
                                "sgstAmount" : 1.0,
                                "igstAmount" : 1.0,
                                "cessAmount" : 1.0,
                                "quantity" : 1.0
                            },
                            "indexName" : "covered-index-for-hsn-autocompute",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "gstinOrgId" : [],
                                "invoiceMetadata.returnPeriod" : [],
                                "isDeleted" : [],
                                "documentGstStatus" : [],
                                "status" : [],
                                "invoiceMetadata.sectionName" : [],
                                "documentDetails.documentType" : [],
                                "hsnCode" : [],
                                "unit" : [],
                                "gstRate" : [],
                                "totalAmount" : [],
                                "assessableAmount" : [],
                                "cgstAmount" : [],
                                "sgstAmount" : [],
                                "igstAmount" : [],
                                "cessAmount" : [],
                                "quantity" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "gstinOrgId" : [ 
                                    "[\"8ca21c57-3cd1-4a1a-9aa3-d9bc668ebd9b\", \"8ca21c57-3cd1-4a1a-9aa3-d9bc668ebd9b\"]"
                                ],
                                "invoiceMetadata.returnPeriod" : [ 
                                    "[\"072022\", \"072022\"]"
                                ],
                                "isDeleted" : [ 
                                    "[false, false]"
                                ],
                                "documentGstStatus" : [ 
                                    "[\"FILED\", \"FILED\"]", 
                                    "[\"FILING_FAILED\", \"FILING_FAILED\"]", 
                                    "[\"NA\", \"NA\"]", 
                                    "[\"RESET_FAILED\", \"RESET_FAILED\"]", 
                                    "[\"STAGED\", \"STAGED\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMISSION_FAILED\", \"SUBMISSION_FAILED\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMITTED\", \"SUBMITTED\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMITTED_FOR_FILING\", \"SUBMITTED_FOR_FILING\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMITTED_FOR_RESET\", \"SUBMITTED_FOR_RESET\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMITTED_FOR_SUBMISSION\", \"SUBMITTED_FOR_SUBMISSION\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMITTED_FOR_SYNC\", \"SUBMITTED_FOR_SYNC\"]", 
                                    "[\"SUBMITTED_FOR_UPLOAD\", \"SUBMITTED_FOR_UPLOAD\"]", 
                                    "[\"SYNCED\", \"SYNCED\"]", 
                                    "[\"SYNC_FAILED\", \"SYNC_FAILED\"]", 
                                    "[\"UPLOADED\", \"UPLOADED\"]", 
                                    "[\"UPLOAD_FAILED\", \"UPLOAD_FAILED\"]"
                                ],
                                "status" : [ 
                                    "[\"GENERATED\", \"GENERATED\"]", 
                                    "[\"GENERATION_FAILED\", \"GENERATION_FAILED\"]", 
                                    "[\"IN_PROGRESS\", \"IN_PROGRESS\"]", 
                                    "[\"NOT_GENERATED\", \"NOT_GENERATED\"]"
                                ],
                                "invoiceMetadata.sectionName" : [ 
                                    "[\"AT\", \"AT\"]", 
                                    "[\"B2B\", \"B2B\"]", 
                                    "[\"B2CL\", \"B2CL\"]", 
                                    "[\"B2CS\", \"B2CS\"]", 
                                    "[\"CDNR\", \"CDNR\"]", 
                                    "[\"CDNUR\", \"CDNUR\"]", 
                                    "[\"EXP\", \"EXP\"]", 
                                    "[\"NIL_RATED\", \"NIL_RATED\"]"
                                ],
                                "documentDetails.documentType" : [ 
                                    "[\"CRN\", \"CRN\"]", 
                                    "[\"DBN\", \"DBN\"]", 
                                    "[\"INV\", \"INV\"]"
                                ],
                                "hsnCode" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "unit" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "gstRate" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "totalAmount" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "assessableAmount" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "cgstAmount" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "sgstAmount" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "igstAmount" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "cessAmount" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ],
                                "quantity" : [ 
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined" : 134,
                            "seeks" : 8,
                            "dupsTested" : 0,
                            "dupsDropped" : 0
                        }
                    },
                    "allPlansExecution" : []
                }```
````

Comment: Are any of your fields arrays? I know mongo can't use a covered query if you're projecting an indexed array field (that was used in the match)